# Removing element directly from React state using delete operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to remove element from an array inside React state without changing arrays length. Is it proper to use `delete` method like this:

```
removeField = (index) => {
  delete this.state.array[index];
};
```

If not, how should I handle that? My actual solution depends on arrays length (not sure if it is correct either).

Comment: Why don't you want to change array length? Most common is to `splice()` and remove the element completely from array or filter a new array

Comment: If you subtract from the array, the length will change.  What is your strategy for maintaining the array length?  Why is that a requirement?

Comment: @jmargolisvt actually `delete` leaves a hole but length remains the same

Comment: because I need to connect data from an API with my array and because those are two different arrays I want to remove elements from one of them without changing its length

Comment: Thanks, @charlietfl!  Didn't expect that. :)

Comment: Not really clear what *"connect data with my array"* means. Can you modify the object instead with a property like "deleted"?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm displaying data from an array, then when user clicks the button I'm sending api request and trying to display data from response connected to the data from array that I'm displaying, so when user clicks a button to delete data from api response array I don't want to change it's index since it's connected to first data array

Comment: So what about adding a deleted property and filtering those out for display? Trying to keep 2 arrays seems over-complicated also

Comment: @charlietfl I need to delete a property from one array, but stay with old length to stay connected with first array order

Answer (score 0):

If you for any reason need to save the array.length:

```
removeField = (index) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
     return {...prevState, array: prevState.array.map((item, id) => id === index ? null : item }
   })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
    removeField = (index) => {
      let arrCpy = {...this.state.array}
      delete arrCpy[index]
      this.setState({ array: arrCpy )}
    };
```

first you make a copy of the array with a spead operator then you delete your index in the copy then set back the new array in states

Comment: why: `let arrCpy = {...this.state.array}` ? It can be `const arrCpy = this.state.array` instead, right?

Comment: No it can't because of imutability, you have to use `let arrCpy = {...this.state.array}` or `let arrCpy = this.state.array.concat()` (`Object.assign` for objects) because if you don't do that your copy will be pointing to this.state.array, changes you make to that array will mutate this.state so you'll have errors (like don't mutate states use setState) or unwanted behavior of your states

Comment: this however won't create expected copy and won't work as expected

Comment: Would `const arrCpy = [...this.state.array]` work?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution here was to use delete method on state copy as mentioned by @Halt, however it might not be the best answer because it can cause some unexpected behaviour. Most proper solution is array.prototype.splice() method - which can replace deleted item with null, however in my example it forced me to add additional restrictions on children components which made them less flexible.